# Should you turn off and drain gas water heater if you leave for 6 months?

Tags: water, water-heater

Water heater when you areA snowbird for six months

Comment: Turning off will save on gas or electric bills, I would only drain it if the temps get below 30.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'd be able to do a better job of helping you if you gave some more details (e.g. where are you located? what kind of heat do you have? will you leave the heat on?).  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: There are many questions on SO-DIY asking this same question, that have long since had valid answers.

Comment: Please see the linked question and see if it addresses yours. If not, please [edit] your question to explain how your situation is different, then flag it and ask for it to be reopened. Thanks and welcome to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I was a snow bird for many years and I would always shut off the gas for the water heater and also shut the valve for the supply line to the water heater. Like Ed mentioned, if the water heater is in an area where the temp will drop below 30 degrees then you'll need to drain it. I left the heat on, set very low, so I didn't have to worry about this, I didn't want to freeze out the home checkers.